# How to increase localStorage limit in node-webkit?

Tags: local-storage, node-webkit

I'm using localStorage to keep a local database within a node-webkit based app and am getting the error:

```
Error: QuotaExceededError: DOM Exception 22
```

While attempting to create new records.  How do you increase the localStorage quota within node-webkit?  Preferably to an unlimited value (or failing  that, at all).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The limit is just removed by this commit: https://github.com/zcbenz/chromium/commit/e1c7731d5bd099ca5544fcf8eda3867d4ce5bab5

Comment: Yep, I made the request that got it removed yesterday - the node-webkit devs have amazing response time :)